# Elastic search aggregtation filter with wildcard

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do a wildcard filter aggregtation. Consider the below query. The first aggregtation i.e the filter is what i would like to perform a wildcard search on.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "xforms.sentence.tokens",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24*"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sentence": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "xforms.sentence.tokens"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "pos_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24*"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "pos": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "xforms.sentence.tokens.tag.keyword"
              }
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use either the [`prefix`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-prefix-query.html) or the [`wildcard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) queries as `match` doesn't supported wildcards.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "xforms.sentence.tokens",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "prefix": {                                           <--- change this
                "xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24"        <--- remove wildcard
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "sentence": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "xforms.sentence.tokens"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "pos_filter": {
          "filter": {
            "prefix": {                                             <--- change this
              "xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24"          <--- remove wildcard
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "pos": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "xforms.sentence.tokens.tag.keyword"
              }
            }            
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Val.. i have raised another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541248/kibana-and-vega-with-nested-aggregations and if you think you can help me with that would very appreciated.