# Kibana and Vega with nested aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega-lite, vega

Given the below **Vega** JSON in **Kibana**, how can i make it dynamic such that when a user on  searches for something in the **search** box it applies to both the **query** and the **pos filter** tags below. So let's say a user types in 'face*' in the **search** box then i want the values marked with **<----- this to change** below to dynamically change

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v4.3.0.json",
  "autosize": "fit",
  "title": "POS COUNT",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "data_table",
      "url": {
        "index": "sa_test_index_data",
        "body": {
          "size": 0,
          "query": {
            "nested": {
              "path": "xforms.sentence.tokens",
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "should": [
                    {
                      "wildcard": {
                        "xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24*" <----- this to change
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sentence": {
              "nested": {"path": "xforms.sentence.tokens"},
              "aggs": {
                "pos_filter": {
                  "filter": {
                    "wildcard": {"xforms.sentence.tokens.value.keyword": "24*"} <----- this to change
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "pos": {
                      "terms": {"field": "xforms.sentence.tokens.tag.keyword"}
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "format": {"property": "aggregations.sentence.pos_filter.pos.buckets"},
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "collect",
          "sort": {"field": ["doc_count"], "order": ["descending"]}
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "data_table_pie_inner",
      "source": "data_table",
      "transform": [
        {
          "type": "aggregate",
          "groupby": ["key"],
          "fields": ["doc_count"],
          "ops": ["sum"],
          "as": ["ff_sum_count"]
        },
        {
          "type": "pie",
          "field": "ff_sum_count",
          "as": ["ff_inner_startAngle", "ff_inner_endAngle"]
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "scales": [
    {
      "name": "scale_color",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "range": {"scheme": "category10"},
      "domain": {"data": "data_table", "field": "key"}
    }
  ],
  "marks": [
    {
      "name": "mark_inner_ring",
      "type": "arc",
      "from": {"data": "data_table_pie_inner"},
      "encode": {
        "enter": {
          "x": {"signal": "width / 2"},
          "y": {"signal": "height / 2"},
          "fill": {"scale": "scale_color", "field": "key"},
          "fillOpacity": {"value": 0.8},
          "stroke": {"value": "white"},
          "startAngle": {"field": "ff_inner_startAngle"},
          "endAngle": {"field": "ff_inner_endAngle"},
          "innerRadius": {"value": 0},
          "outerRadius": {"value": 100},
          "tooltip": {
            "signal": "datum['key'] + ': count ' + datum['ff_sum_count']"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "legends": [
    {
      "fill": "scale_color",
      "title": "POS",
      "orient": "right",
      "encode": {
        "symbols": {"enter": {"fillOpacity": {"value": 0.5}}},
        "labels": {"update": {"text": {"field": "value"}}}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can find some pointers here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/vega-reference.html#vega-queries

Comment: @Val yeah i had checked that out and doesn't help. All the special variables only add data to the **query** but i need data from filter to get into the **aggs** section on the json. Do you have any further ideas? thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confused by the question, but I figure you are looking to incorporate the dashboard filters into the query body aswell. Make sure to use the %...% parameters in your query likeso.

I noticed in the comment you mention it going into the aggs. I don't think this is doable, maybe try using the %...% parameters in there?

```
{
  body: {
    query: {
      bool: {
        must: [
          // This string will be replaced
          // with the auto-generated "MUST" clause
          "%dashboard_context-must_clause%"
          {
            range: {
              // apply timefilter (upper right corner)
              // to the @timestamp variable
              @timestamp: {
                // "%timefilter%" will be replaced with
                // the current values of the time filter
                // (from the upper right corner)
                "%timefilter%": true
                // Only work with %timefilter%
                // Shift current timefilter by 10 units back
                shift: 10
                // week, day (default), hour, minute, second
                unit: minute
              }
            }
          }
        ]
        must_not: [
          // This string will be replaced with
          // the auto-generated "MUST-NOT" clause
          "%dashboard_context-must_not_clause%"
        ]
        filter: [
          // This string will be replaced
          // with the auto-generated "FILTER" clause
          "%dashboard_context-filter_clause%"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```